# How to get xml nametag variants without separate struct

Tags: xml, go, marshalling

I try to create multiple xml's that are almost similar,
but the element nametag is variating a bit:

```
<ELEM3_VARIANT_A></ELEM3_VARIANT_A>
```

and

```
<ELEM3_VARIANT_B></ELEM3_VARIANT_B>
```

How can I handle this without the need of a separate struct for each variant?
The xml name can be dynamically with

```
XMLName: xml.Name{Local: "XMLName"},
```

but how to change the element names (xml nametags like <ELEM2>) ?

```
<XMLName>
  <ELEM1>hello</ELEM1>
  <ELEM2></ELEM2>
  <ELEM3_VARIANT_A></ELEM3_VARIANT_A>
  <ELEM4></ELEM4>
</XMLName>

<XMLName>
  <ELEM1>hello</ELEM1>
  <ELEM2></ELEM2>
  <ELEM3_VARIANT_B></ELEM3_VARIANT_B>
  <ELEM4></ELEM4>
</XMLName>
```

Code example:
https://play.golang.org/p/-4JsZa4kbF3

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

type VariantA struct {
    XMLName xml.Name
    E1      string `xml:"ELEM1"`
    E2      string `xml:"ELEM2"`
    E3      string `xml:"ELEM3_VARIANT_A"`
    E4      string `xml:"ELEM4"`
}


type VariantB struct {
    XMLName xml.Name
    E1      string `xml:"ELEM1"`
    E2      string `xml:"ELEM2"`
    E3      string `xml:"ELEM3_VARIANT_B"`
    E4      string `xml:"ELEM4"`
}


func test(v interface{}) {
    buf, err := xml.MarshalIndent(v, "", "  ")

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error:", err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(string(buf))
    }
}

func main() {

    test(VariantA {
        XMLName: xml.Name{Local: "XMLName"},
        E1:      "hello",
    })


    test(VariantB {
        XMLName: xml.Name{Local: "XMLName"},
        E1:      "hello",
    })


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a custom type that implements the [`xml.Marshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Marshaler) interface.

```
type VarElem struct {
    Name  string
    Value string
}

func (v VarElem) MarshalXML(e *xml.Encoder, start xml.StartElement) error {
    start.Name.Local += v.Name // <- change name of element
    return e.EncodeElement(v.Value, start)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/K0BoSOmLbI4

Comment: Thank you very much, this is a very nice sollution! best regards :-)

Comment: Here a full example with Name and Value: https://play.golang.org/p/PzdTQeo1cPP